# unable to open hyperlink in a new tab which is created from bootstrap-wysiwyg editor

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap-wysiwyg rich text editor in my application and i am not able to open the hyerlink created in a new window.

i am using the bootstrap-wysiwyg.js file which is below. i am not able to figure out how to make the hyperlink created, to open in a new tab.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /** underscoreThrottle()
     *  From underscore http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html
     */
    var underscoreThrottle = function(func, wait) {
        var context, args, timeout, result;
        var previous = 0;
        var later = function() {
            previous = new Date;
            timeout = null;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
        };
        return function() {
            var now = new Date;
            var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
            context = this;
            args = arguments;
            if (remaining <= 0) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = null;
                previous = now;
                result = func.apply(context, args);
            } else if (!timeout) {
                timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
            }
            return result;
        };
    }
    var readFileIntoDataUrl = function (fileInfo) {
        var loader = $.Deferred(),
            fReader = new FileReader();
        fReader.onload = function (e) {
            loader.resolve(e.target.result);
        };
        fReader.onerror = loader.reject;
        fReader.onprogress = loader.notify;
        fReader.readAsDataURL(fileInfo);
        return loader.promise();
    };
    $.fn.cleanHtml = function (o) {
        if ( $(this).data("wysiwyg-html-mode") === true ) {
            $(this).html($(this).text());
            $(this).attr('contenteditable',true);
            $(this).data('wysiwyg-html-mode',false);
        }

        // Strip the images with src="data:image/.." out;
        if ( o === true && $(this).parent().is("form") ) {
            var gGal = $(this).html;
            if ( $(gGal).has( "img" ).length ) {
                var gImages = $( "img", $(gGal));
                var gResults = [];
                var gEditor = $(this).parent();
                $.each(gImages, function(i,v) {
                    if ( $(v).attr('src').match(/^data:image\/.*$/) ) {
                        gResults.push(gImages[i]);
                        $(gEditor).prepend("<input value='"+$(v).attr('src')+"' type='hidden' name='postedimage/"+i+"' />");
                        $(v).attr('src', 'postedimage/'+i);
                }});
            }
        }
        var html = $(this).html();
        return html && html.replace(/(<br>|\s|<div><br><\/div>|&nbsp;)*$/, '');
    };
    $.fn.wysiwyg = function (userOptions) {
        var editor = this,
            wrapper = $(editor).parent(),
            selectedRange,
            options,
            toolbarBtnSelector,
            updateToolbar = function () {
                if (options.activeToolbarClass) {
                    $(options.toolbarSelector,wrapper).find(toolbarBtnSelector).each(underscoreThrottle(function () {
                        var commandArr = $(this).data(options.commandRole).split(' '),
                            command = commandArr[0];

                        // If the command has an argument and its value matches this button. == used for string/number comparison
                        if (commandArr.length > 1 && document.queryCommandEnabled(command) && document.queryCommandValue(command) == commandArr[1]) {
                            $(this).addClass(options.activeToolbarClass);
                        // Else if the command has no arguments and it is active
                        } else if (commandArr.length === 1 && document.queryCommandEnabled(command) && document.queryCommandState(command)) {
                            $(this).addClass(options.activeToolbarClass);
                        // Else the command is not active
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass(options.activeToolbarClass);
                        }
                    }, options.keypressTimeout));
                }
            },
            execCommand = function (commandWithArgs, valueArg) {
                var commandArr = commandWithArgs.split(' '),
                    command = commandArr.shift(),
                    args = commandArr.join(' ') + (valueArg || '');

                var parts = commandWithArgs.split('-');

                if ( parts.length == 1 ) {
                    document.execCommand(command, 0, args);
                }
                else if ( parts[0] == 'format' && parts.length == 2) {
                    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, parts[1] );
                }

                editor.trigger('change');
                updateToolbar();
            },
            bindHotkeys = function (hotKeys) {
                $.each(hotKeys, function (hotkey, command) {
                    editor.keydown(hotkey, function (e) {
                        if (editor.attr('contenteditable') && editor.is(':visible')) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            execCommand(command);
                        }
                    }).keyup(hotkey, function (e) {
                        if (editor.attr('contenteditable') && editor.is(':visible')) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    });
                });

                editor.keyup(function(){ editor.trigger('change'); });
            },
            getCurrentRange = function () {
                var sel, range;
                if (window.getSelection) {
                    sel = window.getSelection();
                    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                    }
                } else if (document.selection) {
                    range = document.selection.createRange();
                } return range;
            },
            saveSelection = function () {
                selectedRange = getCurrentRange();
            },
            restoreSelection = function () {
                var selection;
                if (window.getSelection || document.createRange) {
                    selection = window.getSelection();
                    if (selectedRange) {
                        try {
                            selection.removeAllRanges();
                        } catch (ex) {
                            document.body.createTextRange().select();
                            document.selection.empty();
                        }
                        selection.addRange(selectedRange);
                    }
                }
                else if (document.selection && selectedRange) {
                    selectedRange.select()
                }
            },

            // Adding Toggle HTML based on the work by @jd0000, but cleaned up a little to work in this context.
            toggleHtmlEdit = function(a) {
                if ( $(editor).data("wysiwyg-html-mode") !== true ) {
                    var oContent = $(editor).html();
                    var editorPre = $( "<pre />" )
                    $(editorPre).append( document.createTextNode( oContent ) );
                    $(editorPre).attr('contenteditable',true);
                    $(editor).html(' ');
                    $(editor).append($(editorPre));
                    $(editor).attr('contenteditable', false);
                    $(editor).data("wysiwyg-html-mode", true);
                    $(editorPre).focus();
                }
                else {
                    $(editor).html($(editor).text());
                    $(editor).attr('contenteditable',true);
                    $(editor).data('wysiwyg-html-mode',false);
                    $(editor).focus();
                }
            },

            insertFiles = function (files) {
                editor.focus();
                $.each(files, function (idx, fileInfo) {
                    if (/^image\//.test(fileInfo.type)) {
                        $.when(readFileIntoDataUrl(fileInfo)).done(function (dataUrl) {
                            execCommand('insertimage', dataUrl);
                            editor.trigger('image-inserted');
                        }).fail(function (e) {
                            options.fileUploadError("file-reader", e);
                        });
                    } else {
                        options.fileUploadError("unsupported-file-type", fileInfo.type);
                    }
                });
            },
            markSelection = function (input, color) {
                restoreSelection();
                if (document.queryCommandSupported('hiliteColor')) {
                    document.execCommand('hiliteColor', 0, color || 'transparent');
                }
                saveSelection();
                input.data(options.selectionMarker, color);
            },
            bindToolbar = function (toolbar, options) {
                toolbar.find(toolbarBtnSelector, wrapper).click(function () {
                    restoreSelection();
                    editor.focus();

                    if ($(this).data(options.commandRole) === 'html') {
                        toggleHtmlEdit();
                    }
                    else {
                        execCommand($(this).data(options.commandRole));
                    }
                    saveSelection();
                });
                toolbar.find('[data-toggle=dropdown]').click(restoreSelection);

                toolbar.find('input[type=text][data-' + options.commandRole + ']').on('webkitspeechchange change', function () {
                    var newValue = this.value; /* ugly but prevents fake double-calls due to selection restoration */
                    this.value = '';
                    restoreSelection();
                    if (newValue) {
                        editor.focus();
                        execCommand($(this).data(options.commandRole), newValue);
                    }
                    saveSelection();
                }).on('focus', function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (!input.data(options.selectionMarker)) {
                        markSelection(input, options.selectionColor);
                        input.focus();
                    }
                }).on('blur', function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.data(options.selectionMarker)) {
                        markSelection(input, false);
                    }
                });
                toolbar.find('input[type=file][data-' + options.commandRole + ']').change(function () {
                    restoreSelection();
                    if (this.type === 'file' && this.files && this.files.length > 0) {
                        insertFiles(this.files);
                    }
                    saveSelection();
                    this.value = '';
                });
            },
            initFileDrops = function () {
                editor.on('dragenter dragover', false)
                    .on('drop', function (e) {
                        var dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (dataTransfer && dataTransfer.files && dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
                            insertFiles(dataTransfer.files);
                        }
                    });
            };
        options = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.wysiwyg.defaults, $.fn.wysiwyg.defaults1, userOptions);
        toolbarBtnSelector = 'a[data-' + options.commandRole + '],button[data-' + options.commandRole + '],input[type=button][data-' + options.commandRole + ']';
        bindHotkeys(options.hotKeys);

        // Support placeholder attribute on the DIV
        if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '') {
            $(this).addClass('placeholderText');
            $(this).html($(this).attr('placeholder'));
            $(this).bind('focus',function(e) {
                if ( $(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).text() == $(this).attr('placeholder') ) {
                    $(this).removeClass('placeholderText');
                    $(this).html('');
                }
            });
            $(this).bind('blur',function(e) {
                if ( $(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).text() == '' ) {
                    $(this).addClass('placeholderText');
                    $(this).html($(this).attr('placeholder'));
                }
            })
        }

        if (options.dragAndDropImages) {
            initFileDrops();
        }
        bindToolbar($(options.toolbarSelector), options);
        editor.attr('contenteditable', true)
            .on('mouseup keyup mouseout', function () {
                saveSelection();
                updateToolbar();
            });
        $(window).bind('touchend', function (e) {
            var isInside = (editor.is(e.target) || editor.has(e.target).length > 0),
                currentRange = getCurrentRange(),
                clear = currentRange && (currentRange.startContainer === currentRange.endContainer && currentRange.startOffset === currentRange.endOffset);
            if (!clear || isInside) {
                saveSelection();
                updateToolbar();
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.wysiwyg.defaults = {
        hotKeys: {
            'Ctrl+b meta+b': 'bold',
            'Ctrl+i meta+i': 'italic',
            'Ctrl+u meta+u': 'underline',
            'Ctrl+z': 'undo',
            'Ctrl+y meta+y meta+shift+z': 'redo',
            'Ctrl+l meta+l': 'justifyleft',
            'Ctrl+r meta+r': 'justifyright',
            'Ctrl+e meta+e': 'justifycenter',
            'Ctrl+j meta+j': 'justifyfull',
            'Shift+tab': 'outdent',
            'tab': 'indent'
        },
        toolbarSelector: '[data-role=editor-toolbar]',
        commandRole: 'edit',
        activeToolbarClass: 'btn-info',
        selectionMarker: 'edit-focus-marker',
        selectionColor: 'darkgrey',
        dragAndDropImages: true,
        keypressTimeout: 200,
        fileUploadError: function (reason, detail) { console.log("File upload error", reason, detail); }
    };
    $.fn.wysiwyg.defaults1 = {
            hotKeys: {
                'Ctrl+b meta+b': 'bold',
                'Ctrl+i meta+i': 'italic',
                'Ctrl+u meta+u': 'underline',
                'Ctrl+z': 'undo',
                'Ctrl+y meta+y meta+shift+z': 'redo',
                'Ctrl+l meta+l': 'justifyleft',
                'Ctrl+r meta+r': 'justifyright',
                'Ctrl+e meta+e': 'justifycenter',
                'Ctrl+j meta+j': 'justifyfull',
                'Shift+tab': 'outdent',
                'tab': 'indent'
            },
            toolbarSelector: '[data-role=editor1-toolbar]',
            commandRole: 'edit',
            activeToolbarClass: 'btn-info',
            selectionMarker: 'edit-focus-marker',
            selectionColor: 'darkgrey',
            dragAndDropImages: true,
            keypressTimeout: 200,
            fileUploadError: function (reason, detail) { console.log("File upload error", reason, detail); }
        };
}(window.jQuery));
```

@
i am saving the editor contents and then i am retrieving it in a different page as below.

```
<p class="textAlignLeft" ng-bind-html="editorContent | unsafe"></p>
```

"editorContent" will have the contents entered in the richtext editor, and the hyper link in it has to open in a new window.

in the browser console i am getting the following output.

```
<p class="textAlignLeft ng-binding" ng-bind-html="editorContent | unsafe">ajslkjsak <a href="http://www.google.com">sdsad</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing that would be to bind to click event of anchor tag and open URL in new tab using JavaScript.

Say, the ID of your editor is "editor", the following code would work with it

```
$("a", "#editor").click(function(e) {
  window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank')
});
```

this will bind click event on all the `a` tags inside `editor` div and when the user clicks any of it, the url will be opened in new window.

Update:

using jQuery, it is very easy. First assign an id to your `<p>` tag like

```
<p id="myCustomContent" class="textAlignLeft" ng-bind-html="newsContent | unsafe"></p>
```

Where `myCustomContent` is the id

now use the following code

```
$("a", "#myCustomContent").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

this will loop once on all the anchor tags and make them open in new tab when user clicks on them.

Comment: i am trying to save the editor contents and then retrieve it in a different screen, here i need to open the link in a new tab. i am using <p class="textAlignLeft" ng-bind-html="richText_Editor_Content | unsafe"></p> to display the contents

Comment: i tried the code it didnt work, <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("dkjfhd");
  $("a", "#myCustomContent").each(function() {
     $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
   });
 });
 </script>       the query is called before the contents are retrieved from the service.

Comment: You have to wait until your contents are loaded before running this code.

Comment: i used  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a", "#myCustomContent").each(function() {
     $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
   });
 }); but it was loading before my content was loaded and i tried     $(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});  its is very slow and i dnt want to wait that long to call the code. could you suggest me a way to wait until my contents are loaded.

Comment: It depends on how you are loading the content. Are you loading the content via ajax?